# Improvements on StackOverflow frontend & user experience

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

## My idea

I'm a new user to stackoverflow and I'm loving  the usage of tags to filter questions. This feature is really good because of the huge amount of information the users post dialy, however I've found out that is somewhat tedious to filter each tag I don't want to see.

I mean taking into consideration the fact that SO has around **24.150 tags and 227,182 questions** it's just A LOT of information.

So how about instead of having to write the tags on the sidebar or the user profile we add small icons to the tags?

This would allow faster navigation and make it a lot simpler for users to understand and use SO. Allowing faster filtering and navigation to improve the user experience.

Here's a little example of what I'm talking about:

This way you can filter everything way faster than using the sidebar, thus improving the user experience and allowing the users to focus on the information they really need.

**So what do you think of this idea?**

Answer (score 3):

With your screenshot, it would be visually somewhat cluttered - the screen would become speckled with the icons.

However, the icons could appear or disappear based on mouse hovers, just like the ones for comment voting/flagging do. That would reduce discoverability, but would be much more visually appealing.

Another option would be to allow drag and drop of tags into "interesting" and "ignore" buckets, much like GMail now does for labels.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally found typing the few tags into the list fairly easy to do. I probably ignore or find interesting about 40 tags. I would support a drag and drop idea, but the icons add quite a bit of noise.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the interesting tags and look for the color change.
I can't imagine trying to filter out 24000+ tags, that would really hose the system.

Answer (score 0):

Think of how often you'd actually want to add or remove tags from/to your lists. After just a few weeks, most of the work will be done. But then, the additional icons are not used anymore and just take up screen real estate.

I'm against this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make those icons only appear on the mouseover, which would remove the clutter.

However, drag-and-drop might be a nicer alternative.