# Is there a problem with creating an account on the new site after the question has been moved?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, linked-accounts

I've seen a number of questions ([like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/improvements-on-stackoverflow-frontend-user-experience)) that have been moved between sites where the user is greyed out. As far as I can work out this means that there's no matching account on the new site.

In this case the OP has got an account here on MSO and has linked his(?) other accounts, but the question is still "ownerless".

Is this because the MSO account didn't exist when the question was moved. But when the user created the MSO account the system couldn't assign the question to that account.

Wouldn't it be better to create a linked account on the target site but leave it dormant and only activate it when the user logs in? It would probably require that the user uses the same OpenID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our current plan is to check ownership when a user associates accounts (and on login, for users that are currently affected).

We have all the necessary data; rest assured, we'll make sure you get your migrated questions back - MUST START CODING!

Comment: I wasn't asking for me, I haven't asked many questions and none of them have been migrated...

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, i'm a bit concerned about this as well, specifically with regard to sofaq topics. Maybe it doesn't matter (a good faq is still a good faq), but i'd hate to move a whole lot of topics if the authors they're attached to still actively *want* to be attached and just haven't had the time to spend on MSO.