# Migrated Questions without MSO Accts link to SO Accts?

Tags: feature-request, migration, user-accounts

My apologies if this has already been requested.

When a question is migrated, the usernames are either converted to MSO link (If the authors have an account on MSO) or dimmed-out and made into regular text. Could the latter case be maintained as a link to their SO profile instead? Makes it much easier to review their participation in SO and derive some additional input about their motives, etc.

*Update: Actually, their name should be a link to their account on the site-of-origin, not simply SO.*

Comment: This is a dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/is-there-a-problem-with-creating-an-account-on-the-new-site-after-the-question-ha - though maybe not an exact dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this is feasible (devinb, where are you?), but i'd like to see it as well.

Perhaps user accounts could be automatically migrated if they don't already exist on the target site? I know that's been... problematic in the past, but AFAIK they did work *something* out finally.

Comment: Accepted, but I disagree with auto-account-creation. I'd rather a link to the account-of-origin.

Answer (score 0):

Better: Link the name to a random profile from any of the other three sites.

What would be *really* nice is if when they came here, a banner dropped down and said, "Hey, I enjoy cookies, and while I was eating some, I saw that you're `username`. I'll bet you came here to find your question/answer that's now here on MSO! Here's a link to claim your MSO account! Welcome to MSO, two drink minimum!"

I don't think that they can migrate accounts without authenticating via OpenID for this specific domain. You need that key from the OpenID provider, which they don't just give out all willy-nilly. But a notification of how to reclaim your little slice of awesome would be nice.