# Can a question be migrated to a site on which the user has been manually suspended by a moderator?

Tags: support, migration, account-suspension

Technically, a user does not even need to have an account on a site for one of their questions to be [migrated there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148761/336163). There is a specific provision in Stack Exchange code to [block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/336163) migration of a question to a site on which the user has received an automated *question ban*.

If a user has received a manual site suspension from a moderator (the one which fixes the user's rep at 1 and blocks posting, commenting, editing, and chatting), can a question posted by them on *another site* be migrated to the site on which they are suspended?

I'm not asking whether this sort of migration is a *good idea*. Except in the most blatant cases of an extremely high quality, but off-topic question, it is probably *not a best practice* to migrate a question to a site where the question asker will not be able to further contribute. My question is whether such a migration is *preemptively blocked by the system* the same way it is for a question-banned user or whether such a migration is left to the judgment of moderators or closevoters.

For what it's worth, this question is inspired by a real case of a question I recently saw on a SE site that could arguably be considered a candidate for migration (off-topic on the site where asked, marginally on-topic elsewhere) and where the question-asker actually *was* suspended on that elsewhere site, but I am asking in the general sense, rather than asking for a judgment on whether that specific question should be migrated.

Comment: Answered by the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/377968): "A migration can be automatically blocked before it even gets migrated if any of the following conditions apply: The user is question-banned or suspended on the destination site"