# My question was migrated to another stack exchange site before I created a login - and now I can't claim the reputation:

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, migrated-questions

My question here:
[Does gravity travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/does-gravity-travel-at-the-speed-of-light)

was migrated to another stack exchange site (physics) before I created a login - and now that I have created a login can't claim the reputation: (still at 101 :)

Comment: Make sure you associate your accounts

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/is-there-a-problem-with-creating-an-account-on-the-new-site-after-the-question-h

Comment: Where was it migrated from? The link back to the original site is missing.

Comment: The accounts are definitely associated

Comment: @ChrisF it was migrated from astronomy here: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/does-gravity-travel-at-the-speed-of-light

Comment: And it looks like Astronomy was closed and merged into Physics.

Comment: @hawkeye - you need to add `?noredirect=1` onto the end of that link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have attached your account to the question manually. These issues are usually handled automatically, but in case of a site merge (as in this case, Astronomy was merged into Physics), this doesn't work yet.