# Account didn't link properly, How can I link or claim rep points

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I created a question on another exchange (Open Source beta) while logged in. The question showed up under a default user name user2295. I used the same email to post my question and received the email to set my password. My question still shows up under this user2295.  How can I claim my reputation? I used the same email and thought it would link accounts.

I saw a similar problem here:
[My question was migrated to another stack exchange site before I created a login - and now I can't claim the reputation:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133976/my-question-was-migrated-to-another-stack-exchange-site-before-i-created-a-login)

my post:

[The download for source is a newer version than the version shipped](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/the-download-for-source-is-a-newer-version-than-the-version-shipped)

my actual user name:
ajputnam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to only be solved by going to the Contact Us link for SE.

It is down on the bottom of the page between "mobile" and "feedback". This is for certain problems only the Stack Exchange staff can help you with, like this problem. You might want to consider merging the accounts into one, or choose the "Other" option since they both have the same e-mail, which is very rare and is definitely a bug only they can fix.

Remember to fill in all boxes and be as clear as you can when you are explaining your problem. Hopefully, a SE staff member can email you back with to help you fix your problem!